# my html and javascript button to change language doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if any of you can help me and tell me why my code does not work.
What I want to do is that when I press the EN button, the language is changed to English and when I press the ES button, the language is changed to Spanish. The problem is that the javascript code that I have made does not work.

```js
const english = document.getElementById("en")
const espanol = document.getElementById("es")
const hey = document.getElementById("hey")
const text = document.getElementById("text")


english.addEventListener("click", function() {
  change(english, espanol);
});

espanol.addEventListener("click", function() {
  change(espanol, english);
});

function change(lang1, lang2) {

  if (lang1.innerHTML == "EN") {

    hey.innerHTML = "Hey, I'm  English";
    text.innerHTML = "I am a text in the English language";

  } else {

    hey.innerHTML = "Hey, yo soy Español";
    text.innerHTML = "Yo soy un texto en el idioma ingles ";

  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.switch>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked~.off {
  color: #000;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked~.on {
  color: #fff;
}

.switch>span.on {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 2px;
  color: #000;
}

.switch>span.off {
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}

.check-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.check-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #facf0f;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:before,
input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:before {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #facf0f;
  -webkit- -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  -ms-border-radius: 52px;
  -o-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.2s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.2s;
  transition: margin 0.2s;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked+label {}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="language-toggle" class="check-toggle check-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
  <label for="language-toggle"></label>
  <span class="on" id="en">EN</span>
  <span class="off" id="es">ES</span>
</div>
<h1 id="hey"> Hey, I'm English</h1>
<div>
  <p id="text">I am a text in the English language
  </p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Skyance11441/pen/gOeQPJO

Comment: Works fine here... click the `en`, it goes to English, click the `es`, it goes to Spanish

Comment: Doesn't work for me, probably because you're initialising `projects` and `contact`, but updating `hey` and `text` in your event listener.

Comment: The text was changed to "text" and "hey" and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `change` event on the input field instead

```js
const english = document.getElementById("en")
const espanol = document.getElementById("es")
const projects = document.getElementById("hey")
const contact = document.getElementById("text")
const toggle = document.getElementById("language-toggle")

toggle.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    change(espanol, english);

  } else {
    change(english, espanol);
  }
})

function change(lang1, lang2) {

  if (lang1.innerHTML == "EN") {

    hey.innerHTML = "Hey, I'm  English";
    text.innerHTML = "I am a text in the English language";

  } else {
    hey.innerHTML = "Hey, yo soy Español";
    text.innerHTML = "Yo soy un texto en el idioma ingles ";
  }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.switch>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked~.off {
  color: #000;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked~.on {
  color: #fff;
}

.switch>span.on {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 2px;
  color: #000;
}

.switch>span.off {
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}

.check-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.check-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #facf0f;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:before,
input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:before {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #facf0f;
  -webkit- -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat+label:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  -ms-border-radius: 52px;
  -o-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.2s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.2s;
  transition: margin 0.2s;
}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked+label {}

input.check-toggle-round-flat:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="language-toggle" class="check-toggle check-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
  <label for="language-toggle"></label>
  <span class="on" id="en">EN</span>
  <span class="off" id="es">ES</span>
</div>
<h1 id="hey"> Hey, I'm English</h1>
<div>
  <p id="text">I am a text in the English language
  </p>
</div>
```